# hbase 0.94.11 and hadoop version

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have a Hadoop cluster with version 1.2.1 and recently i also downloaded hbase 0.94.11 to try out. I able to setup hbase t run in distributed mode but when i checked the web gui status, it stated that the Hadoop version is 1.0.4. I noticed that this is because hbase use the hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar file comes together with hbase. So my question is should i replace this jar file with the hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar so that hbase can use the latest hadoop-core jar file? And does it matter?

Cw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do that if 1.0.4 works for you. Because the newest version may bring you any other problems and just replace hadoop-core.jar is unsafe. If you want to upgrade the HBase, please follow the [official guide](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html).

Hope it helps.